# VSCode debug console does not stay scrolled to the bottom

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode to develop something using the Flutter Framework. The Flutter extension writes logs to the debug console.
I scroll the debug console to the bottom, so it stays auto-scrolling / tailing the log.

Whenever the flutter logs write a large amount of data at once, the debug console stops tailing the log all of a sudden.

Has anyone observed this same issue before and found a solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is actually a VSCode issue (which should be fixed now), take a look at [#117674](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/117674).

There is currently no fix, you'll have to wait until the issue is fixed by the VSCode team.

A workaround is actually **disabling** Word Wrap in your VSCode settings. Go to your settings, search for Debug Console and *untick* Word Wrap. Although disabling it seems to introduce [other problems](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/117674#issuecomment-871454281) in the terminal.

Answer (score 7):

**Go to settings (Ctrl+), search for "`Word Wrap`" and *untick* it.**

[image]

As stated here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/118702

If that doesn't work, there's an issue on Github which is still open to date. Keep an eye on it and wait for the fix:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/117674

Comment: debugConsole.wordWrap is already set to true by default.

Comment: True that, I actually misread the answer on issue #18702, it's fixed by disabling word wrap